# Classifying strings of characters using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-processing

Have there been any efforts made to classify images with multiple characters in them using deep learning? I would be particularly interested in a model that generates new strings rather than attempts to segment them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the blog on number plate recognition I have read recently:

> https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/

[image]